# neo4j slow lucene index query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm retrieving data from a index in my neo4j database, and I'm having some problems with the execution time. I'm trying a query where I simply count the resulting values. In my production database I'm doing more complex calculations. Anyway, my query looks something like this,

```
START person = node:user_index('muncipalityCode:(1278 OR 1285 OR 1283 OR 1293 OR 1284 OR 1261 OR 1282 OR 1262 OR 1281 OR 1280 OR 1273) ')
return count(person)
```

The count returns 278418 in approximately 20 seconds(2.5-3 seconds second time, when the cache is warm). Sure, I'm returning a quite large dataset. However, it is not immense.

Is there somewhere I can reduce this bottleneck or some configuration settings that I should look into? I've tried warming up the cache on startup, but I can't fit all data in ram on my production server, so it backfires(My server has 16GB RAM).

My database has the following attributes.
10 329 245 nodes
97 923 564 properties
50 697 532 relationships

Comment: Can you translate this code the the Java API and time it to see if it is the Index or the count?

Comment: i think the OR condition might be a problem (at least it is in sql where sometimes the index is ommited when there are many OR conditions).if you divide the query into separate START phases like this, does it help? `START person1 = node:user_index('muncipalityCode:1278), person2=node:user_index('muncipalityCode:1285 ),person3 = .... RETURN count(person1)+count(person2)+count(person3)...`

Comment: How many people are returned? And can you model the zipcodes as indexed nodes and connect the people to those? Then the lucene query only has to return 15 entries. Lucene also keeps its results around so it might also related to memory usage and GC.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Do you think it would be faster to model the zipcodes as nodes than using a lucene index? The zipcodes would have between 10 and 100k relationships each. From what I've seen, fetching large sets of relationships from a single node slows down cypher queries quite drastically(Though I'm certain I might be wrong=) )

Comment: Actually the match part of a Cypher query is quite fast. You just want to avoid using where clauses. So index the zip codes, load the ones you need in START like you did now except load the zipcodes in stead of the persons, then do MATCH person-[:muncipality_code]->zipcode RETURN count(person) and see if that's faster, but I believe it will be.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to verify whether the problem is in the index or elsewhere in the code. If the corresponding Luke query is fast, then likely the problem lies elsewhere.